# How to add event listener to my javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, animation, addeventlistener

I have an animation on my page that slides a div into the screen, pushing the current div in the screen out. While it is animating, an ajax request is sent to grab a page and put it into the div.

For some reason, my code works OK on Firefox but stutters using Chrome.

Here is the page: (try clicking the left eye)

http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/homesite/index.html

What I want to do (as per recommendation of @jfriend00) is add an event listner to the slideOut() function to make it so the ajax request won't start until the slideOut() has finished. Separating the ajax call and the animation should lessen the load of the code and therefore prevent Chrome from stuttering as it does now.

here is my slide out function:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
            function SlideOut(element) {
                var opened = $(".opened"),
                    div = $("#" + element),
                    content = $("#content");
                opened.removeClass("opened");
                div.addClass("opened");
                content.removeClass().addClass(element);
            }
```

CSS:

```
    #content {
        margin: 0 auto;
        position:relative;
        left:0;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.9s ease;
        transition: all 0.9s ease;
    }
    #content.right {
        left:-1150px;
    }
    #content.left {
        left:1150px;
    }
    #content.bottom {
        top:-300px;
    }
    #content.top {
        top:1100px;
    }

    #content div {
        cursor:pointer;
    #left {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:-1800px;
        height:100%;
        width:1750px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.9s ease;
        transition: all 0.9s ease;
        background-color: #1a82f7;
        /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#C6421F), to(#2F2727));
        /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #C6421F, black);
        /* Firefox 3.6+ */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #C6421F, black);
        /* IE 10 */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #C6421F, black);
        /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #C6421F, black);
    }

    #left.opened {
        left:0;
    }
    #left-content{
        margin-left:70px;
        position:relative;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.9s ease;
        transition: all 0.9s ease;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="fullContainer">

    <div id="right">
        <div class="return-right">
            <p>click me</p>
        </div>
        <div id="resume">
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="left">

            <div class="return-left">
        <p>click me</p>
        </div>
            <div id="left-content">
        </div>


    </div>
    <div id="top">
            <div class="return">
        <p>click me</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
            <div class="return">
        <p>click me</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="centerContainer">
    <div id="relativeContainer">
        <div id="content" class="center">
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It might be best just to use firebug on the actual site.

Thanks!

Comment: You would make the AJAX call first, and then upon success, run the animation.

Comment: when i do this, chrome seems to just wait until the content is loaded and then just places the page in the screen - no slide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to use the transitionend event to track when #left's transitions complete. You will have to check for browser prefixes which I've done below. After that we can use the designated prefix and listen. Once fired, you can make your ajax call.

**Javascript:**

```
var myDiv, transition;
myDiv = document.getElementById('left');

if('ontransitionend' in window) {
  // Firefox
  transition = 'transitionend';
} else if('onwebkittransitionend' in window) {
  // Chrome/Saf (+ Mobile Saf)/Android
  transition = 'webkitTransitionEnd';
} else if('onotransitionend' in myDiv || navigator.appName == 'Opera') {
  // Opera
  // As of Opera 10.61, there is no "onotransitionend" property added to DOM elements,
  // so it will always use the navigator.appName fallback
  transition = 'oTransitionEnd';
} else {
  // IE - not implemented (even in IE9) :(
  transition = false;
}

myDiv.addEventListener(transition, function(){
  //make ajax call here.
}, false);
```

Comment: this seems perfect - works nicely in chrome but won't work in firefox. any idea? thanks reza

Comment: I forgot to include the mozTransitionend. I may have a simpler way for you to do this.

Comment: $("#left").bind("webkitTransitionEnd mozTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend", function(){
  //ajax call
});

Comment: thats perfect works like a charm except there is one strange side effect - after loading the left div, I click back to the main page and the links no longer register until a few seconds later - there is also a change in the color of the page. any idea what is causing this/does this problem occur on your setup? thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Do you have a dev link? I tried using the one in the comment but it doesn't appear that anything is sliding there.

Comment: sorry - the problem only occurs in chrome for some reason